# Extensions of Hilbert class fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K/F$ be a Galois extension of number fields. Is it true that the Hilbert class field $H_K$ of $K$ is an extension of the Hilbert class field $H_F$ of $F$ ?

If the class number of $F$ is $h_F > [K:F] h_K$, then we find a counterexample, but I don't know how to check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since the compositum $K\cdot H_F$ is an unramified Abelian extension of $K$, and so is contained in $H_K$.

Comment: Thank you. Why is $KH_F / K$ unramified? I only see that if $v$ is a place of $K$ that ramifies, then $v\vert_F$ is a place of $F$ ramifying already in $K$.

Comment: @Alphonse Just localise the whole setup at your place $v\mid_F$ and then all should be clear.

Comment: Apparently, $KH_F/K$ is unramified by Prop 173 [here](http://courses.washington.edu/mnotes/ant/notes.pdf).

Comment: Two more questions : 1) The fact $H_F \subset H_K$ holds even if $K/F$ is not Galois, right?  2) So in general, we have $h_F/h_K \leq [K:F]$, right? Many thanks!

Comment: May I have some hints for my 2 little questions above, please? Then I think that I can accept your answer.

Comment: Just think about the local situation: if $K/F$ and $L/F$ are finite extensions of local fields, with $L/F$ unramified, prove that $K\cdot L/K$ is also unramified. @Alphonse

Comment: Does the fact $H_F⊂H_K$ hold even if K/F is not Galois? And in general, we have $h_F/h_K≤[K:F]$, right? Many thanks!

Comment: There's no normality needed in these examples. @Alphonse